What filtering options are available for Playwright HTML reports?
I'm trying to figure out what options are available to filter the HTML report output from Playwright.
I already know the following exist from viewing the report:

s: (for status) with options 'passed', 'failed', 'flaky', 'skipped'.
@: (for a tag, followed by the tag text)
p: (for project followed by the project name)

What other options are available?
I'm looking for a way to filter by the error for failed tests. So if I have 100 failed tests, and 50 of them are failing with a Timeout error, I'd like to be able to filter by the error message/text instead of having to drill down into each and every failed test to find out which ones failed due to a timeout error.
Is this possible in the current HTML reporter, or would this require a custom reporter configuration?
